# Testing for non-zero values above and below the diagonal of a matrix

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, matrix, count-data, contingency-tables

I have a $n\times n$ contingency matrix comparing count data (classification) of two procedures. I want to test for non-zero values above and below the diagonal (different classifications in both procedures). Most tests recommended (McNemar-Bowker, for example) are designed to test diagonality, but they are not suited for my comparison (I do not care if there is symmetry in the deviations, only if there are deviations). Is there a test that can help me identify these deviations? Or should I use a binomial test $2n$ times (for each row and column), checking if the proportion of non-diagonal values is significantly different from a given value (let's say $1-p(coincidence)<0.1$)?

Comment: I have tried the `binom.test` with some column (17 correct classifications and 0 incorrect ones) and it does not reject the null hypothesis that $p>0.9$ ($p-value=0.1668$). How is this even possible?

Comment: There's likely a problem with how you're formulating this question because if even a single off-diagonal count is nonzero, that's *definite* evidence the proportion in nonzero!  What are you really trying to find out?

Comment: Well, maybe I exaggerated a little, but in the comment, it is somewhat clear: I would like to test the alternative $p>0.9$ for deviations of the diagonal (coincidence in classification). For the data in the example I just ran `binom.test(c(17,0),p=.9,alternative = "greater")` and the $p-value$ obtained was $0.1668$.

Comment: Maybe, in this case, I was looking at the wrong alternative. If switch it from `"greater"` to `"less"` I obtain the result I want, although in a different perspective, i.e., the probability of coincidence is not significantly less than $0.9$.